# split a large file by a delimiter- out of memory

Tags: macos, shell, awk

I want to split a large file to many files based on a delimiter. The delimiter I am aiming in my input file is // (double forward slash in a newline). Part of my file is like

```
..
...
 7141 gatttaggca gtgaaaactt agtagccgac aaggtgaaag atgccgagaa tgtactaagg
 7201 gtaaaggcag ctaaaacaga ctttaccgat agcaccaacc tatcggtcat cactcaagac
 7261 ggaggctttt atagctttga ggtgagttat cacaccacgc cacaacctct taccattgat
 7321 tttggtagag gaatgcccca aggcaataat gtgaaatcgg atattctctt ttctgacaca
 7381 ggctgggaat cacctgcggt agcacagatt attatgtcgt ctatct
//



LOCUS       KE150251                6962 bp    DNA     linear   CON 
14-JUN-2013
DEFINITION  Capnocytophaga granulosa ATCC 51502 genomic scaffold
        acFDk-supercont1.18/ whole genome shotgun sequence.
 ...
..
```

I also want to include these slashes as the last line of the generated files.

I failed do it by csplit in my Mac, and end up with the following awk script:

```
awk -v RS='^//' '{ outfile = "output_file_" NR; print > outfile}' Input.gbk
```

But I am getting following error:

```
awk(56213,0x7fffb585b3c0) malloc: *** 
mach_vm_map(size=18446744071562067968) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
awk: out of memory in readrec 1
source line number 1
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I think `RS` is the problem. Afaict, awk read until `RS`. You could read and write line by line until the marker. Anyway, why csplit doesn't work?

Comment: Umm.. I am not sure. I have tried csplit Input.gbk "^//+1" "{*}"  ..

Comment: You forgot the slash that marks the regex. `csplit file '/^\/\//' '{*}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe since you have NOT closed files(new output files) they are eating up the memory. Could you please try following once.

```
awk -v RS='^//' '{close(outfile)} {outfile = "output_file_" NR; print > outfile}' Input.gbk
```

***EDIT:*** one more try with another approach. Since I believe your file have many lines between `//` so memory is getting filled up  by `RS`  so better to use a flag approach rather than `RS` approach.

`awk -v outfile="output_file_1" -v count=1 '/^\/\//{print > outfile; close(outfile);outfile = "output_file_" ++count;next} {print > (outfile)}' Input.gbk`

***Explanation of above approach:*** Checking for line which starts from `//` and increment value in outputfile name and reset value of output file name variable, also I am closing output file here else you may get error too many files opened in background too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Bob, Could you please try my EDIT code now and let me know then? I haven't tested though since no mac and no big files with me.

Comment: Now I am getting: 
awk: null file name in print or getline input record number 1, file Input.gbk
 source line number 1

Comment: I have downloaded the file from: http://downloads.ihmpdcc.org/data/reference_genomes/body_sites/Oral.gbk

Comment: @Bob, I edited my code please check now, looks like your very first line doesn't start from `//` so try it now and let me know we should be good here.

Comment: @Bob, please check my edit, this will add // to last of file too.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Last question, why the files start with a //

Comment: @Bob, what happened, you removed this as correct answer, I believe it worked for you?

Comment: actually it does. But I don't want my files to start with //. It must only remain in the last line of each file. Sorry for the miscommunication .

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a library to parse large GenBank files. Here's one way using [Bio::SeqIO::genbank](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::SeqIO::genbank), which returns [Bio::Seq](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Seq) objects and writes them to separate files by display id. Put the following into a file called `split_genbank.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Bio::SeqIO::genbank;

my $stream = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $ARGV[0], -format => 'GenBank');

while ( my $seq = $stream->next_seq ) {
    my $id = $seq->display_id();

    my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format => 'GenBank', -file => ">$id.gbk");
    $out->write_seq($seq);
}
```

Then call it using:

```
perl split_genbank.pl input.gbk
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting RS, you make awk read in data until the separator. You say your file is large, so it may be that the resulting records are bigger than the memory available to awk for processing.

For your application, you could use the default value for RS and compute the effective NR by hand by incrementing a counter whenever the delimiter is read:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        pre = "output_file_"
        n = 1
        outfile = pre n
    }
    {
        print > outfile
    }
    /^\/\// {
        close(outfile)
        n++
        outfile = pre n
    }
' Input.gbk
```

Comment: Perfect. One last question , if I need to include the // as the last line in each file, where do I need to edit? Thank you!

Comment: I noticed I'd missed that just before you commented. What about at the end of the final file if there isn't a trailing delmiter?

Comment: I think each file will have the delimiter; if they doesn't, then printing as the above code is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to GNU csplit.
You can use it:

```
csplit Input.gbk '/^\/\//+1' '{*}'
```

Your original command doesn't work because `csplit` expects a regular expression, not a fixed string.